# jquery show div after second div visible

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

I've made my first slider with optional div contains content called for example `.description`, and I'm searching how can I animate this `div` after certain slide is shown up. I tried something like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("#test").hasClass('flex-active-slide')){
        $(".description").fadeIn(2000);
    };
```

But it does not work for me, could anyone show me the right direction to achieved that ?

Comment: How is this if triggered? As I see this if will only be triggered once and this is when the document is ready. Have you tried to bind this to the click handler for your slider?

Comment: But i dont want this slider to be clickable, i mean there is pagination but its gonna work as slideshow. And yes my problem is i dont know how to trigger it correctly ;)

Comment: I would like to trigger it when li class is changed for "active-slide" but idk how ;)

Comment: do you have tried to wrap your if check into a setInterval?

Comment: nope ;) im kinda new to jquery, how should it be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.animate` has a callback, you can use it:

```
$(".slide1").animate({opacity:'show'},1000,function(){
   $(".description").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Good luck

Comment: Could you explain this to me a litle more I mean where the dots are I shuld place div id or class of my element , right ? and the code where uve written "place ur code here" shall there be somehting like " '   if($("#test").hasClass('flex-active-slide')){'"

Comment: i have added my answer, it's simple, so you just to show the slide and if you certain defined slide is displayed, you can fadeIn the description

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing brace for the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("#test").hasClass('flex-active-slide')){
        $(".description").fadeIn(2000);
    }
}; // this
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I just missed it while copyied here ;)
Still nothing happens, tried   $(".description").hide(); also nothing happens

Comment: In order for the `fadeIn` method to work, the `display` property of the object needs to be set to `display:none` before the fadeIn method is called. In your css or in some earlier jquery code try setting the display css property of the .description div to none and let me know if that works.

Comment: Nope it doesnt work also. hover it works for me even without display:none on another element of the website.
 hm maybe if i give u website i work on it it would be easier to find out ?

Comment: More information is good information :) maybe post a link to a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates your problem a little more clearly.

Comment: website is hurompolska.pl and the problem is with the slider there on top of site;) hm is position aboslute the problem there ?

Answer (score 0):

I build now a little jsFiddle for this :-)

you could use setInterval like this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  // your code here
}, 800) // checks all 800ms
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL9R8/2/)

Comment: I can see, however this fiddle is not working i guess cuz this yellow thing "hello im here "is not showing for me ;) on the other hand is this like showing  sstuff after certain time ?

Comment: I hope you have clicked the Click me button :-) because this adds in my example the flex-active-slide class to the header. The setInterval starts every X milliseconds the given function.

Comment: i cant see any button;) and tried to click everywhere and nothing happens ;)

Comment: So now :D I had forgot to update the link here to... The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wL9R8/3/

Comment: Ye know is fine, but there is a litle misunderstanding cuz i know how to make something like that;) I need this wihout clicking cuz my slider is a slideshow and the class is given for the actually showed slide ;) u can see it here hurompolska.pl

Comment: Hmm the click is not the relevant information in the fiddle :-) it only simulates the add of the class flex-active-slide. The more important part is the setInterval-part

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it xD I dont know if its properly or not but it works as i wished ;) 
If someone knows how to make it easier (becouse now its set on timers, not attached to slides) please let me know ;)

```
$(function () {
 var $anchors = $('.description');
 (function _loop(idx) {
$anchors.removeClass('highlight').eq(idx).addClass('highlight');
setTimeout(function () {
  _loop((idx + 1) % $anchors.length);
}, 7000);
$('.description').fadeIn(2000);
}(0));
});

window.setInterval(function() {

if($('#test2.highlight')){

     $('.description').removeAttr('style');
      $('.description').fadeIn(2000);
    }    
}, 7000); // checks all 800ms
```